# SwiftUI View and Swift Package Manager

Tags: swiftui, swift-package-manager

I am trying to create a Swift Package that is basically a single SwiftUI View. I have created a sample here to display what is happening.  What the packaged does, doesn't matter, I have just included some @State and @Binding variables in the View so that I get the same error I get in my real package.
The View struct is this.

```
import SwiftUI

public struct SampleView: View {
    @Binding var myNum:Int
    @State var fixedText:String = ""
    var myText = ""
    var optional: String?


   public  var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if optional != nil {
                Text(optional!)
            }
            Text(myText)
            Text("Parent number: \(myNum)")
            Text("\(fixedText)")
            Button("Increment num") {
                self.myNum += 1
            }.foregroundColor(.blue)
            Button("Change Parent Text") {
                self.fixedText = "Only Changes Child"
            }.foregroundColor(.blue)
        }.background(Color.red)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
}
```

When I add the package and import it into one of the views in my project, I should be able to use Do something like this as I can do if the View is not part of a Swift Package:

```
 SampleView(myNum: $myNum,
             fixedText: parentText,
             myText: "Display Text Passed from parent")
```

However, I get no code completion and I get the error:

```
'SampleView' initializer is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level
```

I have tried all sorts of initializations on the SampeView struct, but keep getting all sorts of different errors. I just don't understand how to fix the access levels here.  Can anyone help?  Screenshot is here also.
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is expected declaration in Package (tested with Xcode 11.2.1 / iOS 13.2.2). Please note that `@State` are not allowed to be used outside of View, so all you need to make in sync should be passed via `Binding`:

```
public struct SampleView: View {
    @Binding var myNum:Int
    @Binding var fixedText:String
    var myText: String
    var optional: String?

    public init(myNum: Binding<Int>, fixedText: Binding<String>, 
                myText: String = "", optional: String? = nil) {
        self._myNum = myNum
        self._fixedText = fixedText
        self.myText = myText
        self.optional = optional
    }
    
    public var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if optional != nil {
                Text(optional!)
            }
            Text(myText)
            Text("Parent number: \(myNum)")
            Text("\(fixedText)")
            Button("Increment num") {
                self.myNum += 1
            }.foregroundColor(.blue)
            Button("Change Parent Text") {
                self.fixedText = "Only Changes Child"
            }.foregroundColor(.blue)
        }.background(Color.red)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
}
```

and usage:

```
@State private var myNum: Int = 1
@State private var parentText = "Test"
var body: some View {
    SampleView(myNum: $myNum,
               fixedText: $parentText,
               myText: "Display Text Passed from parent")
}
```